# Rails: sleep until there is data to respond with (streaming + multithreading)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, keep-alive, ruby-2.0

I am building a Rails/Javascript application which is supposed to support real-time notifications. JavaScript is:

```
var chat;

$(document).ready(function(){
    chat = $('#chat');
    chat.append('mmm');
    (function poll(){
        $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:3000/get_messages", success: function(data){
            //Update your dashboard gauge
            chat.append(data);
        }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
    })();
});
```

The route:

```
match 'get_messages', to: 'real_time_notifs#get_messages', :via => :get
```

Here is the controller's method:

```
def get_messages
  # sleep ??? will it stop the whole application?
  render :json => ['message body']
end
```

I want that JavaScript will receive an answer only if there is something to display (for example, new message appeared in database table) without making a whole application to stop. Could you suggest how to organize `get_messages` method?

I need the solution which will not block the rest of application while waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this

Although I don't have huge experience, you should be thinking about it from another perspective (not just sending Ajax poll requests):

---

[**SSE's (Server Sent Events)**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

I'd recommend you use SSE's

The sent updates are not in the usual HTTP scope (uses its own [mime type](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) -- `text/event-stream`), which I believe means they are completely asynchronous (doesn't matter what you're doing in the app etc)

SSE's are basically done through the front-end by deploying a JS `listener`. This polls the server for any updates, but unlike Ajax, only listens for the `text/event-stream` mime):

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert(event.data);
};
```

The efficient part is that you can then update this with [ActionController::Live::SSE](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live/SSE.html) in Rails. I don't have any experience with this, but it basically allows you to send updates via the `text/event-stream` mime type

---

[**WebSockets**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Websockets basically open a perpetual connection with your server, allowing you to receive content above the normal HTTP scope

My experience does not extend to "native" websockets (we've successfully used [`Pusher`](http://pusher.com), and are working on our own websock implementation); but I can say that it's basically a more in-depth version of SSE's

You'll have to use JS to authenticate the client-server connection, and once connected, the browser will `listen` for updates. I'm not sure about the mime-type for this, but reading up on [`ActionController::Live`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html) will give you some insight into how it works

---

Either one of these methods will do as you need (only send / receive updates as they are available)

Comment: SSEs are great, but there is a problem: we still need a controller with action where is a loop which writes to stream. This writing is controlled by some start/stop mechanism, which is often based on `connection.raw_connection.wait_for_notify` supported by PostgreSQL only. The question is: could this mechanism be replaced with `ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe` or not.